# Why is sudo required for almost anything?

Tags: linux, bash, arch-linux, sudo, manjaro

Whenever I use `git` to clone stuff or use `ssh-keygen` I have to use `sudo` for some reason. I mainly used Git Bash for doing such things on Windows and you don't have to use `sudo` to do such actions. Is this a normal thing with Linux or is it my distro? I use Manjaro Linux.

Comment: No, that's not normal.  Are you trying to write to a directory for which your user doesn't have permission?  If you want to get a useful answer here, you need to provide details including a full and complete version of any error message that you see.

Comment: @John1024 Yeah, I'm trying to write to some other directories. The directory I try to use these commands on (mainly `git`) are my external drives (``run/media/Misc`).  But in my home directory I still have to use `sudo` to install something using `pip`. I get a permission denied error.

The error: `error: could not create '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/test.py': Permission denied`

Comment: FYI, `/usr/lib/python3.7` is not in your home directory and a normal user does not have permission to write to that directory.  Please [edit] your question (rather than comments where the formatting is awful)  and include full details on the command you are running and all associated error messages.

Comment: And in particular, you *shouldn't* mess with `/usr/lib`, because this will clash with your distro's package system. If you want to install additional stuff manually, use the subhierarchy in `/usr/local`.

Comment: @apap04 you want to learn about `virtualenv`! I can recommend this (not mine) video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5vscPTWKOk

Comment: everything seems to be working fine now.. not sure what was going on there